# Creating a recursive tacit function in J

Tags: recursion, j, tacit-programming

I'm a newcomer to J and I've been trying to create a Fibonacci function as an exercise (always the second function I create when learning a language). I just can't figure out what exactly is wrong in my way of doing it. I have tried to define it as tacit, but it gets hung if argument is greater than one.

```
fib =: [ ` (($: (]-1)) + ($: (]-2))) @. (>&1)
```

I've also attempted to create it explicitly, and that worked fine.

```
fib =: 3 : 'if. y>1 do. (fib (y-1)) + (fib (y-2)) else. y end.'
```

I tried to create a tacit out of that by replacing 3 with 13, but it threw an error.

```
   fib =: 13 : 'if. y>1 do. (fib (y-1)) + (fib (y-2)) else. y end.'
|spelling error
|   if. y>1 do. (fib (y-1)) + (fib (y-2)) else. y end.
|   ^
|   fib=:    13 :'if. y>1 do. (fib (y-1)) + (fib (y-2)) else. y end.'
```

So, I'm asking for someone to explain what exactly I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative that I think is both clearer and more concise:

```
fibn =: (-&2 +&$: -&1)^:(1&<) M."0
```

Compare with a more canonical (pseudocode) definition:

```
fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) if n > 2 else n
```

First, instead of using `` [ ` `` with `@. (>&1)`, which uses a gerund, it's better to use `^:(1&<)`. For `f(n) if cond(n) else n`, using the `^:` conjunction is more idiomatic; `^:0` means "do nothing" and `^:1` means "do once," so the intent is clear. `@.` is better suited to nontrivial behavior.

Second, using the `&` bond/compose conjunction simplifies the train significantly. Repeated uses of `[:` and `]` are rather confusing and opaque. Refactoring using `&` puts together related operations: first, split `n` into two, namely `n-2` and `n-1`, and second, add together the `fibn` of those two numbers.

And, lastly, `"0` for list handling and `M.` for memoizing. `M.` is rather important from a performance perspective, as a straightforward implementation of the canonical definition will call `fib(2)` excessively. You can have your cake (a simple definition) and eat it too (good performance) with the built-in memoization adverb.

Source for this particular definition: `f0b` on [this page](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Fibonacci%20Sequence).

Comment: This is pretty much what I would do now. My answer shows how I found my solution, which I knew was wrong. Thank you for taking the time to write this anyways.

Comment: No problem. I saw the timestamps, so I guessed you would probably have improved significantly and wouldn't personally need this advice, but I thought it'd be good to leave this for any newbies.

Comment: I'll make this the accepted answer, as it does have some good information.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I found it. I ran only the recursive block through tacit generator and got this block.

```
   13 : '(f y-1) + (f y-2)'
([: f 1 -~ ]) + [: f 2 -~ ]
```

Then I inserted that to the original piece, getting this.

```
fib =: [ ` (([: $: 1 -~ ]) + [: $: 2 -~ ]) @. (>&1)
```

And that works like a charm. I also inserted `" 0` to the end to make it accept lists.